# trouble installing 13.04 on samsung series 9

Tags: grub2, samsung, boot-repair

I have been having the hardest time trying to install Ubuntu on my Samsung series 9 NP900X3A-A03US.

After installing, it goes in an infinite reboot loop. I tried different ways of installing, the latest is in legacy mode with uefi turned off in BIOS. BIOS version is 08HL. Here is the paste bin link after running boot-repair:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6000365/

I am a bit of an Ubuntu newbie, and this installation has been quite frustrating. I am almost resorting to just installing windows 8 on the machine and be done with it but I don't want to give up just yet.

Any help would be great.

Comment: have you disabled UEFI mode (or enabled Legacy boot) in your Bios? see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Yes, UEFI is disabled, and the installation is the default legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the `recommended repair` (written at the bottom of the report)?

Have you changed any default option while running Boot Repair?

For the easiest way, try re-installing Ubuntu keeping the bootloader location to default (most probably /dev/sda).

Also, if you're planning for a dual-boot along with Windows, install Windows first. It becomes stubborn while identifying any other OS. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It currently is the default installation, and the recommended repair was already run. Still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff I have installed Ubuntu on my Samsung series 5 laptop. I searched your laptop on the internet and see it has a 128GB SSD (Solite State Drive). I know there is a issue in the BIOS where you have to disable the fast boot mode. I followed this link and it worked for me.See this [link](http://schoolsplay.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/install-ubuntu-linux-on-a-samsung-series-5-ultrabook-with-ssd/) for more info. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for looking it up! Unfortunately, there isn't a way of turning on or off fast boot mode in the series 9 bios as far as I can tell.